# Error with join SQL in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

```
$select = $this->getSelect();
$select->from("table");
$select->join("users", "table.id = users.idTable");
$select->join("test", "test.idUser = users.id");
```

My code works perfectly without the second join (test), why?
What I've wrong with that? I don't have any errors, but console of the browser show me an 500 Internal error server. If I cut the join(test) the script will work right.

Comment: Can you paste the error details? You can find those in your http server error log or in your application log.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that line to your $select :

```
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```